# How can I make this animation faster on MatLAB

Tags: matlab

This is the code. I need help making the animation faster.

write the code to make a ball bounce back and forth between to walls. The ball bounces in the form of cos2 () where θ goes from 0˚ to 360˚ with a length of 1000.

height of the ball is 28 inches from the center.

distance between the two walls is 30 inches.

radius of the ball is 1 inch

the ball will bounce back and forth 20 times

**Code Block:**

```
   r = 1; 

   hmax = 28; 
   n = 1000;
   h = linspace(0,hmax,n);
   t = linspace(0,360,n);
   k = 0;

  pt = 1/6000;

  x = zeros(length(h),length(t));
  vx = x;
  y = x;
  vy = y;
  a = r+h;
  b = r+hmax/2*(cosd(t).^2)+hmax/2;
  for i = 1:n
      x(i,:) = a(i)+r.*cosd(t);
      y(i,:) = b(i)+r.*sind(t);
      vx(i,:) = r+r.*cosd(t);
      vy(i,:) = r+h.*sind(t);
  end

  figure(3)
  ball_bounce1= plot(x(1:500:end),y(1:500:end),'c','linewidth',3);
  axis([-1 31 -1 31])

  grid on 
  while k < 10 
      if rem(k,2) == 0 
         for i = 1:n
             set(ball_bounce1,'XData',x(i,:),'YData',y(i,:));
             pause(pt)
         end
      end
  if k > 10 
     break
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just Something That Might be Useful:*

Something that may or may not be interesting to you is using an animated line with a marker representing the ball. This script follows the absolute, `abs()` of a cosine path. The cosine frequency can also be adjusted by changing `2*pi` within the line:

```
y = Amplitude.*abs(cos(linspace(0,2*pi,Number_Of_Samples))) + Ball_Offset;
```

This script uses the `drawnow` to repeateadly draw new points that are queued/added by the `addpoints()` function.

### GIF of Ball Movement (a lot smoother in MATLAB):

[image: GIF of Ball Movement]

### Script:

```
clf;
Animated_Plot = animatedline('MaximumNumPoints',1,'Marker','o','MarkerSize',10);

Amplitude = 28;
Wall_Distance = 30;
Number_Of_Samples = 500;
Ball_Offset = 0.4;

axis([0 Wall_Distance 0 Amplitude+0.2*Amplitude]);
xlabel("Position Between Wall 0 and Wall 30"); ylabel("Amplitude");
title("Ball Movement");

x = linspace(0,Wall_Distance,Number_Of_Samples);
y = Amplitude.*abs(cos(linspace(0,2*pi,Number_Of_Samples))) + Ball_Offset;

%Mirroring and repeating%
x = [x flip(x)];
y = [y flip(y)];

x = repmat(x,1,20);
y = repmat(y,1,20);

for Point = 1: length(x)
    addpoints(Animated_Plot, x(Point), y(Point));
    drawnow
end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: does the code u presented have the length on theta as 1000?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "the length on theta as 1000"? Are you referring to the length of the vector representing theta (number of theta/angle samples)? Or possibly you mean the length of the wave for a single cycle (proportional to the amplitude and frequency)?

Comment: i'm kind of confused. the code you presented is much easier then what I did for this. i will update my code can you check it out please

Comment: @MichealTr7 can you run my code and help me with my graph. the ball is not going all the way down. it stops in the middle when I run my code

Comment: for you the ball bounces off the x axis. but the code i wrote the ball bounces in the middle

Comment: Yeah, sure I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you soo much i have been working on this for 3days. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, I quickly looked over it and was wondering the reasoning behind `hmax/2` in the line `b = r+hmax/2*(cosd(t).^2)+hmax/2;`.

Comment: the reason for that is if i don't have that the ball doesn't show on the graph

Comment: When I remove the `hmax/2` this seems to be the culprit of the DC/constant offset. When I changed that line to `b = r+hmax*(cosd(t).^2);`

Comment: the main problem i am having is that the ball doesn't go all the way down

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SOO MUCH

Comment: I tested it and after I changed that line it goes all the way down it bounces from 0 to 28 repeateadly.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Reduce number of vertices of ball. You are drawing 1000 segments to draw a circle, 16 or 32 segments would be enough for that. To do so, you need `x` and `y` matrices should be `m by n`, where `m` is the number of time slices and `n` is the number of segments.

Firs step is to define two `h` and two `t` vectors, `h1` and `t1` with `m` elements, and `h2` and `t2` with `n` elements. After doing so, the animation runs pretty smooth here.

And as a side note, I think your movement modelling is wrong. The ball in your code moves like top figure, I believe it should go like the bottom one:
[image]

Comment: can you show me that in code form? yeah i can't figure out how to do that. can you make edits to my code please. so it does what you are showing me

Comment: @JasonRobert, of course I can, but it doesn't benefit you. Don't give up, you have come a long way so far. It will be more fun if you finish it by yourself.

Comment: i have been trying for 2 days. I just can't seem to figure it out. it will mean alot if you could help with it. your the first person who actually helped. i really appreciate it

Comment: @JasonRobert I'm sure everyone here wants to help, otherwise there's no point in contributing here in SO. But you should know that SO is not a code generator service. There are rules about asking questions and answering them: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.

Comment: i know can you help me set up the code on how i can make my code look like the 2nd graph.